# Assign multiple environment variables to a single variable and expand them on command

Tags: bash, environment-variables

Let's say I want to repeat the same string of environment variables before running various incantations of a command

```
if [[ some_thing ]]; then
    TZ=GMT LC_ALL=C LONG_ENV_VAR=foo my_command
elif [[ some_other_thing ]]; then
    TZ=GMT LC_ALL=C LONG_ENV_VAR=foo my_command --with-arg
else
    TZ=GMT LC_ALL=C LONG_ENV_VAR=foo my_command --with-other-arg
fi
```

Is there a way to combine those? Some options

1. Set them via `export`

   ```
   export TZ=GMT
   export LC_ALL=C
   export LONG_ENV_VAR=foo
   if [[ ]] # ...
   ```

   This works but I would rather not have them continue to be set in the environment.
2. Attempt to create a variable variable!

   ```
   local cmd_args="TZ=GMT LC_ALL=C LONG_ENV_VAR=foo"
   ```

   Unfortunately when I tried to run this via:

   ```
   $cmd_args my_command
   ```

   I got `TZ=GMT: command not found`.
3. Just list them all out every time.

I also tried Googling for this, but "environment variable variable" isn't the easiest term to search for and I didn't get anywhere. Is there a fix for what I'm trying to do in #2? or am I stuck with some version of #1 and unsetting the vars afterwards?

Comment: Kevin, if any of the existing answers solve your problem, please consider accepting it by using the checkmark next to it. Thank you!

Answer (score 12):

I might use a subshell for this:

```
(
  export TZ=GMT LC_ALL=C LONG_ENV_VAR=foo
  if [[ some_thing ]]; then
    exec my_command
  …
  fi
)
```

That allows you to clearly set the variables once; have them present for anything you run inside the subshell, and also not be present in the main shell's environment.

Answer (score 12):

There are various ways of doing this. Personally, I find functions clearer:

```
run_this(){
   TZ=GMT LC_ALL=C LONG_ENV_VAR=foo "$@"
}

if [[ some_thing ]]; then
    run_this my_command
elif [[ some_other_thing ]]; then
    run_this my_command --with-arg
else
    run_this my_command --with-other-arg
fi
```

Answer (score 6):

Point 2. is possible via `env`:

```
local env_args="greppable1=foo greppable2=bar"
env $env_args perl -E 'say for grep /greppable/, keys %ENV'
```

This may be complicated by bash word splitting rules if there's spaces in any of the env args, though.

Comment: You should clarify that the contents of `$env_args` have no effect in variable expansion in the command string itself: `env A=B echo "$A"` echos nothing (or echos what `$A` already contained).

Comment: @alexis - does `A=B echo "$A"` behave any differently for you?

Comment: It's the same (except that the `env` command allows pre-expansion of the variable definition string, which was what the OP needs). I should have included the `env`, but my point applies equally to both versions: any variables in the command itself will be expanded before the custom definitions take effect. The adjusted environment is only useful inside the program. On the other hand, `A=B; echo "$A"` (as two commands) will of course echo `B`.

Answer (score 0):

this is what your arg array is for:

```
if    thing
then  set --
elif  something
then  set -- --with_arg
else  set -- --other_arg
fi&&  TZ=GMT LC_ALL=C LONG_ENV_VAR=foo my_command "$@"
```

Remember: an empty `"$@"` != `""`. It's just *not there*.