# Should variables be quoted when executed?

Tags: shell-script, quoting, variable

The general rule in shell scripting is that variables should always be quoted unless there is a compelling reason not to. For more details than you probably want to know, have a look at this great Q&A: [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346/22222).

Consider, however, a function like the following:

```
run_this(){
    $@
}
```

Should `$@` be quoted there or not? I played with it for a bit and couldn't find any case where the lack of quotes caused a problem. On the other hand, using the quotes makes it break when passing a command containing spaces as a quoted variable:

```
#!/usr/bin/sh
set -x
run_this(){
    $@
}
run_that(){
    "$@"
}
comm="ls -l"
run_this "$comm"
run_that "$comm"
```

Running the script above returns:

```
$ a.sh
+ comm='ls -l'
+ run_this 'ls -l'
+ ls -l
total 8
-rw-r--r-- 1 terdon users  0 Dec 22 12:58 da
-rw-r--r-- 1 terdon users 45 Dec 22 13:33 file
-rw-r--r-- 1 terdon users 43 Dec 22 12:38 file~
+ run_that 'ls -l'
+ 'ls -l'
/home/terdon/scripts/a.sh: line 7: ls -l: command not found
```

I can get around that if I use `run_that $comm` instead of `run_that "$comm"`, but since the `run_this` (unquoted) function works with both, it seems like the safer bet.

So, in the specific case of using `$@` in a function whose job is to execute `$@` as a command, should `$@` be quoted? Please explain why it should/shouldn't be quoted and give an example of data that can break it.

Comment: `run_that`'s behaviour is definitely what I'd expect (what if there's a space in the path to the command?). If you wanted the other behaviour, surely you'd unquote it at the *call*-site where you know what the data is? I'd expect to call this function as `run_that ls -l`, which works out the same in either version. Is there a case that made you expect differently?

Comment: @MichaelHomer I guess my edit here prompted this: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/250985/70524

Comment: @MichaelHomer for some reason (probably because I still haven't had my second cup of coffee) I hadn't considered spaces in the command's arguments or path, but only in the command itself (options). As is so often the case, this seems very obvious in retrospect.

Comment: There is a reason why shells still support functions instead of simply stuffing commands into an array and executing it with `${mycmd[@]}`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The problem lies in how the command is passed to the function:

```
$ run_this ls -l Untitled\ Document.pdf 
ls: cannot access Untitled: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access Document.pdf: No such file or directory
$ run_that ls -l Untitled\ Document.pdf 
-rw------- 1 muru muru 33879 Dec 20 11:09 Untitled Document.pdf
```

`"$@"` as in `run_that` should be used in the general case where your function is prefixed to a normally written command (as above).

Trying to use the unquoted `$@` as in `run_this` makes it impossible to pass a filename with whitespace. None of these attempts will work:

```
$ run_this 'ls -l Untitled\ Document.pdf'
ls: cannot access Untitled\: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access Document.pdf: No such file or directory
$ run_this 'ls -l "Untitled\ Document.pdf"'
ls: cannot access "Untitled\: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access Document.pdf": No such file or directory
$ run_this 'ls -l Untitled Document.pdf'
ls: cannot access Untitled: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access Document.pdf: No such file or directory
$ run_this 'ls -l' 'Untitled Document.pdf'
ls: cannot access Untitled: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access Document.pdf: No such file or directory
```

The reason it doesn't work is that the unquoted expansion goes through word splitting, which splits on any whitespace and doesn't provide means for interpreting quotes or such (for that, you'd need to use `eval`).

See also e.g.

- [BashFAQ 050](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) (or "I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!")
- [How can we run a command stored in a variable?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/444946/170373)

Comment: It was indeed your edit which prompted this. For some reason it just didn't occur to me to test with a file name with spaces. I have absolutely no idea why not, but there you go. You're quite right of course, I don't see a way to do this correctly with `run_this` either.

Comment: @terdon quoting's become so much of a habit that I assumed you'd left `$@` unquoted accidentally. I should have left an example. :D

Comment: Nah, it is indeed so much of a habit that I tested it (wrongly) and concluded that "huh, maybe this one doesn't need quotes". A procedure commonly known as a brainfart.

Comment: You can't pass a filename with spaces to `run_this`. This is basically the same problem you run into with stuffing complex commands into strings as discussed in [Bash FAQ 050](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

Answer (score 11):

It's either:

```
interpret_this_shell_code() {
  eval "$1"
}
```

Or:

```
interpret_the_shell_code_resulting_from_the_concatenation_of_those_strings_with_spaces() {
  eval "$@"
}
```

or:

```
execute_this_simple_command_with_these_arguments() {
  "$@"
}
```

But:

```
execute_the_simple_command_with_the_arguments_resulting_from_split+glob_applied_to_these_strings() {
  $@
}
```

Does not make much sense.

If you want to execute the `ls -l` command (not the `ls` command with `ls` and `-l` as arguments), you'd do:

```
interpret_this_shell_code '"ls -l"'
execute_this_simple_command_with_these_arguments 'ls -l'
```

But if (more likely), it's the `ls` command with `ls` and `-l` as arguments, you'd run:

```
interpret_this_shell_code 'ls -l'
execute_this_simple_command_with_these_arguments ls -l
```

Now, if it's more than a simple command you want to execute, if you want to do variable assignments, redirections, pipes..., only `interpret_this_shell_code` will do:

```
interpret_this_shell_code 'ls -l 2> /dev/null'
```

though of course you can always do:

```
execute_this_simple_command_with_these_arguments eval '
  ls -l 2> /dev/null'
```

Answer (score 5):

Looking at it from the bash/ksh/zsh perspective,
`$*` and `$@` are a special case of general array expansion. Array expansions aren't like normal variable expansions:

```
$ a=("a b c" "d e" f)
$ printf ' -> %s\n' "${a[*]}"
 -> a b c d e f
$ printf ' -> %s\n' "${a[@]}"
-> a b c
-> d e
-> f
$ printf ' -> %s\n' ${a[*]}
 -> a
 -> b
 -> c
 -> d
 -> e
 -> f
$ printf ' -> %s\n' ${a[@]}
 -> a
 -> b
 -> c
 -> d
 -> e
 -> f
```

With the `$*`/`${a[*]}` expansions you get the array joined with the first value of `IFS`—which is space by default—into one giant string. If you don't quote it, it gets split like a normal string would.

With the `$@`/`${a[@]}` expansions, the behavior depends on whether the `$@`/`${a[@]}` expansion is quoted or not:

1. if it is quoted (`"$@"` or `"${a[@]}"`), you get the equivalent of 
   `"$1" "$2" "$3" #...`
   or `"${a[1]}" "${a[2]}"  "${a[3]}" # ...`
2. if it isn't quoted  (`$@` or `${a[@]}`) you get the equivalent of 
   `$1 $2 $3 #...`
   or `${a[1]} ${a[2]}  ${a[3]} # ...`

For wrapping commands, you most definitely want the **quoted @** expansions (1.).

---

More good info on bash (and bash-like) arrays: https://lukeshu.com/blog/bash-arrays.html

Comment: Just realized I'm referring to a link starting with Luke, while wearing a Vader mask. The force is strong with this post.

Answer (score 4):

Since when you don't double quote `$@`, you left all the globbing issues in [the link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346/22222) you gave to your function.

How could you run a command named `*`? You can not do it with `run_this`:

```
$ ls
1 2
$ run_this '*'
dash: 2: 1: not found
$ run_that '*'
dash: 3: *: not found
```

And you see, even when error occurred, `run_that` gave you a more meaningful message.

The only way to expand `$@` to individual words is double quotes it. If you want to run it as a command, you should pass the command and it parameters as separated words. That the thing you did on the caller side, not inside your function.

```
$ cmd=ls
$ param1=-l
$ run_that "$cmd" "$param1"
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 cuonglm cuonglm 0 Dec 23 17:33 1
-rw-r--r-- 1 cuonglm cuonglm 0 Dec 23 17:33 2
```

is a better choice. Or if your shell support arrays:

```
$ cmd=(ls -l)
$ run_that "${cmd[@]}"
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 cuonglm cuonglm 0 Dec 23 17:33 1
-rw-r--r-- 1 cuonglm cuonglm 0 Dec 23 17:33 2
```

Even when the shell does not support array at all, you can still [play with it by using `"$@"`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/137566/38906).

Answer (score 3):

Executing variables in `bash` is a failure-prone technique. It's simply impossible to write a `run_this` function which correctly handles all the edge cases, like:

- pipelines (e.g. `ls | grep filename`)
- input/output redirections (e.g. `ls > /dev/null`)
- shell statements like `if` `while` etc.

If all you want to do is avoid code repetition, you're better off using functions. For example, instead of:

```
run_this(){
    "$@"
}
command="ls -l"
...
run_this "$command"
```

You should write

```
command() {
    ls -l
}
...
command
```

If the commands are only available at run time, you should use `eval`, which is specifically designed to handle all the quirks which will make `run_this` fail:

```
command="ls -l | grep filename > /dev/null"
...
eval "$command"
```

Note that `eval` is [known](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048) for security issues, but if you pass variables from untrusted sources to `run_this`, you will face arbitrary code execution just as well.

Answer (score 0):

The choice is yours. If you do not quote `$@` any of its values undergo additional expansion and interpretation. If you do quote it all of the arguments passed the function are reproduced in its expansion verbatim. You'll never be able to reliably handle shell syntax tokens like `&>|` and etc either way without parsing out the arguments yourself anyway - and so you're left with the more reasonable choices of handing your function one of either:

1. Exactly the words used in the execution of a single simple command with `"$@"`.

...or...

2. A further expanded and interpreted version of your arguments which are only then applied together as a simple command with `$@`.

Neither way is wrong if it is intentional and if the effects of what you choose are well understood. Both ways have advantages one over the other, though the advantages of the second are seldom likely to be particularly useful. Still...

```sh
(run_this(){ $@; }; IFS=@ run_this 'ls@-dl@/tmp')
```

---

```
drwxrwxrwt 22 root root 660 Dec 28 19:58 /tmp
```

...it isn't *useless*, just rarely likely to be of much *use*. And in a `bash` shell, because `bash` doesn't by default *stick* a variable definition to its environment even when said definition is prepended to the command-line of a special builtin or to a function, the global value for `$IFS` is unaffected, and its declaration is local only to the `run_this()` call.

Similarly:

```sh
(run_this(){ $@; }; set -f; run_this ls -l \*)
```

---

```
ls: cannot access *: No such file or directory
```

...the globbing is also configurable. Quotes serve a purpose - they're not for nothing. Without them shell expansion undergo extra interpretation - *configurable* interpretation. It used to be - with some very *old* shells - that `$IFS` was *globally* applied to *all* input, and not just expansions. In fact, said shells behaved very like `run_this()` does in that they broke all input words on the value of `$IFS`. And so, if what you're looking for is that very old shell behavior, then you *should* use `run_this()`.

I'm not looking for it, and I'm fairly hard pressed at the moment to come up with a useful example for it. I generally prefer for the commands my shell runs to be those which I type at it. And so, given the choice, I would almost always `run_that()`. Except that...

```sh
(run_that(){ "$@"; }; IFS=l run_that 'ls' '-ld' '/tmp')
```

---

```
drwxrwxrwt 22 root root 660 Dec 28 19:58 /tmp
```

Just about anything can be quoted. Commands will run quoted. It works because by the time the command is actually run, all input words have already undergone *quote-removal* - which is the last stage of the shell's input interpretation process. So the difference between `'ls'` and `ls` can only matter while the shell is interpreting - and that's why quoting `ls` ensures that any *alias* named `ls` is not substituted for my quoted `ls` command word. Other than that, the only things which quotes affect are the delimiting of words *(which is how and why variable/input-whitespace quoting works)*, and the interpretation of metacharacters and reserved words.

So:

```sh
'for' f in ...
 do   :
 done
```

---

```
bash: for: command not found
bash:  do: unexpected token 'do'
bash:  do: unexpected token 'done'
```

You'll never be able to do that with either of `run_this()` or `run_that()`.

But function names, or `$PATH`'d commands, or builtins will execute just fine quoted or unquoted, and that's exactly how `run_this()` and `run_that()` work in the first place. You won't be able to do anything useful with `$<>|&(){}` any of those. Short of `eval`, is.

```sh
(run_that(){ "$@"; }; run_that eval printf '"%s\n"' '"$@"')
```

---

```
eval
printf
"%s\n"
"$@"
```

But without it, you're constrained to the limits of a simple command by virtue of the quotes you use *(even when you don't because the `$@` acts like a quote at the beginning of the process when the command is parsed for metacharacters)*. The same constraint is true of command-line assignments and redirections, which are limited to the function's command-line. But that's not a big deal:

```sh
(run_that(){ "$@";}; echo hey | run_that cat)
```

---

```
hey
```

I could have as easily `<` redirected input or `>` output there as I did open the pipe.

Anyway, in a round-about way, there is no right or wrong way here - each way has its uses. It's just that you should write it as you intend to use it, and you should know what you mean to do. Omitting quotes can have a purpose - otherwise there wouldn't *be* quotes at all - but if you omit them for reasons not relevant to your purpose, you're just writing bad code. Do what you mean; I try to anyway.